# Why is my program keep trying to take all of available CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, numba

[image]

As you can see from above the process keep trying to take as many cpu resource as possible. On the picture above I am only using  camera sources to test. As you could see below that I repeat each process for each camera available. Initially I thought the reason is that my cpu have not enough power but adding several more camera. None of the camera is laggy in fact and all is on about the same fps as only 1 camera which make me question what is the actual cause because apparently it is not cause by lack of resources from my CPU. Below is my main program.

```
import cProfile
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import threading
import videoPlayerThreading as vpt
from objDect import objDect as od

def main(videoSource):
    obd = od( videoSources = videoSource, GPU=True )
    
    getFrame = vpt.getFrames(videoSource).start()
    showFrame = vpt.showFrames(getFrame.frame).start()

    getFrame.videoInit(videoSource)

    print("Showing Frame...")
    while True:
        print("thread count : ",threading.active_count())
        frame = getFrame.frame
        #frame = obd.predictYolo(frame)
        

        showFrame.frame = frame
 
        if getFrame.doVideo == False or showFrame.doVideo == False:
            getFrame.stop()
            showFrame.stop()
            sys.exit()

def working():
    cams=[0,1,2]
    for cam in cams:
        Process(target=main,args=(cam,)).start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    working()
```

and here is my getFrame and showFrame class:

```
class getFrames():
    def __init__(self, 
                 videoSource:Union[int,str]=0):
        self.stream = self.videoInit(videoSource)
        self.hasFrame, self.frame = self.stream.read()
        self.doVideo = True

    def videoInit(self,
                  videoSource:Union[int,str]):
        try:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoSource)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Video source error: {e}")

        return cap

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.getFrames, args=()).start()
        return self

    def getFrames(self):
        while self.doVideo:
            if not self.hasFrame:
                self.stop()
            else:
                (self.hasFrame, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def stop(self):
        self.doVideo = False
        self.stream.release()

class showFrames():
    def __init__(self, 
                 frame:cv2=None):
        self.frame = frame
        self.doVideo = True

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.showFrame, args=()).start()
        return self

    def showFrame(self):
        while self.doVideo:
            cv2.imshow("Video", self.frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
                self.doVideo = False

    def stop(self):
        self.doVideo = False
```

and lastly here is my objdect.predict :

```
 @jit(nopython=True, parallel=True) 
    def predictYolo(self,
                    frame:cv2) -> cv2:
        net = self.net

        height, width, channels = frame.shape
        
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),swapRB=True, crop=False)       
        net.setInput(blob)
        outs = net.forward(self.output_layers)
        
        class_ids = []
        confidences = []
        boxes = []
        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > 0.8:
                    # Object detected
                    center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                    w = int(detection[2] * width)
                    h = int(detection[3] * height)

                    # Rectangle coordinates
                    x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                    y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)

        indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.7, 0.4)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
        classes=self.classes
        colors = np.random.uniform(130, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            if i in indexes:
                x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
                label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
                if label=="With Helmet":
                    label="Helmet"
                    color=(0,255,0)
                elif label=="Without Helmet":
                    label="Violation"
                    color=(0,0,255)
              
                self.createBB(x,y,w,h,frame=frame,label=label,color=color)
        self.frame=frame
        #print("sending finish processed frame ...")
        return frame
```

Is there any Error in the program that cause the code to always try to take maximum cpu resource? Thanks.

Comment: 60% != as much CPU time as possible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It is true that is why I have actually tried to close all my program and only run my code with only 1 cam it take a whopping 90 percent which show that even now i don't have that much free space it actually works absolutely fine. A moment let me recreate it for you :D

Comment: This code `cams=[0,1,2]     for cam in cams:         Process(target=main,args=(cam,)).start()` looks like you're starting 3 processes

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yap that is true, but on the one I screenshot the CPU I only test on 1 camera. My bad for not making it clear.